# Extracting url and headline of a list of articles from a given url

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/

Hi, so I'm trying to get the list of all the urls and main headings from articles given on a html page. So the link above is the main page and clicking the 'next article' link leads to the next article with a link like this:

http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/Hodg001.html

"Hodg001.html" href which continues until 147th article. This page has a 'next article' link that leads to the next article and so on.

I'm trying to extract the url and the heading  from each article and create a dataframe with to save into a csv file. I'm totally clueless and don't know how to proceed now

```
base_url = 'http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/'
req = requests.get(base_url)
print(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.h1)
links = soup.findAll("a")
print(links)
headings = soup.findAll("h1")
print(headings)
for link in links:
    print(link.get("href")) ##only gets 1
for i in headings:
    print(i) #doesn't work
```

Can anyone please explain how I can proceed? I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

In the code below a few things are happening:

- set the a `base_url` as the links are relative links.  Not absolute
- keep track of the `next_url` for the while loop
- the `next_link_class` is just a placeholder to find which

  -tag is needed
- `data` will contain the links and headings
- `csv_path` is the path to your export file

Next we tell the script to keep on fetching links and extract information as long as the next_link is populated.

After it's done, it will write the data to a the provided path for the csv file.

I must admit I didn't let it run through to the end - so you may need to catch it differently if no next_link available on the html-page.  But this should get you well on your way.

```
import csv
import bs4
import requests

url_base = 'http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/'
next_url = 'http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/Hodg001.html'
next_link_class = 'nextLink'
csv_path = 'export.csv'
data = []

while next_url:
    link_list.append(next_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(next_url).content)

    try:
        next_url = url_base + soup.find('p', {'class': next_link_class}).a['href']
    except AttributeError:
        break  # This exception should be thrown when the last page is reached.
        # The loop should break at that point and dump the data to the csv-file

    d = {
        'url': next_url,
        'heading': soup.find('h1').string
    }
    data.append(d)
    print(d)


with open(csv_path, 'w') as f:
    c = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
    c.writeheader()
    [c.writerow(i) for i in data]
```

This code above will provide you with a dictionary of links and headings. And save it all to the given `csv_path`

```
In [20]: data
Out[20]:
[{'url': 'http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/Vick002.html',
  'heading': 'Hodgson shoulders England blame'},
 {'url': 'http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/Yach003.html',
  'heading': 'Vickery out of Six Nations'},
 {'url': 'http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/Lapo004.html',
  'heading': 'Yachvili savours France comeback'},
 {'url': 'http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/Lews005.html',
  'heading': 'Laporte tinkers with team'},
 {'url': 'http://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/Fumi006.html',
  'heading': 'Lewsey puzzle over disallowed try'}]
```

Comment: Hey so I need the heading to match the link of the article. So 'Hodgson shoulders England blame' should be for ttp://comp20008-jh.eng.unimelb.edu.au:9889/main/Hodg001.html. So how can I get it in order so the heading and article link match in the dataframe?

Comment: This script creates a list of dicts where every entry contains the heading and its matching link - and then dumps it into a csv-file as you asked.  However, from you choice of words, I'm guessing you are talking about pandas.  Unfortunately I cannot help you with this part.